# Flutter - How to clear TextFormField after form save/submit

Tags: flutter

With a Flutter form that uses TextFormField, how do I clear the text field after the form have been saved/submitted?

Do I have to use a Text controller?

Comment: You could use the initial value of the TextFormField and set it to empty string
or just use a text controller

Answer (score 1):

First define `controller`:

```
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
```

then use it like this:

```
TextFormField(
   controller: controller,
   onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
     controller.clear();
   },
),
```

here in `onFieldSubmitted` you can get the `value` and save it in somewhere else and then clear the `controller` and by that `TextFormField` will get clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Form widget, add a Key to it, and after submitting the form you can do:
`_formKey.currentState?.reset();`
This will reset the status of the TextFormFields that are contained in your Form.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `TextEditingcontroller`

```
 final myController = TextEditingController();
```

dispose of it after use

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: myController,
      onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
        //do smth with value
        // if you want to clear form field 
        myController.clear();
      },
    );
  }
```